# Animated plotting with LaTex?

Tags: graphics, plot

I am not a LaTeX pro, that's why I don't know if the following is possible and how I could do it.

I have a graphic (a plot, jpg) and it shows a time series. I know in PowerPoint it is possible that if one comes to the slide in the presentation, the time series curve is drawn, so not just showing up/appearing, but it is slowly drawn as a curve, so one could see that the computer actually draws the line, as a human would do if he draws the line. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: why not: use the beamer package and its methods for incremental slide creation. Then, configure your favority LaTeX plot tool such that it draws the first N points for slide 1, the first N+k for slide 2, the first N+2k for slide 3 etc. Commonly used plot tools are http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf or pstricks (although I do not know if pstricks works together with beamer). Try it - if you run into problems, you can ask here for details.

Comment: BTW: welcome on TeX.SE!

Comment: thanks for your help, but, I use R, I have a time series and what do I have to do now? I do not know how to do this in R? Thanks for your help

Comment: PSTricks supports Beamer.

Comment: Have a look at the animate package on ctan

Comment: but how can I give my time series as the input?
I dont get it, mh, what a pitty, well I guess I have to do it without the animations. I like PP more, it would last less than 5 minutes to do something like this....

Comment: It seems as if you feel uncomfortable with your decision (?) to use LaTeX. If you want to use LaTeX then you should have good starting points here on this site (export your timeseries data from R, learn how to plot it in LaTeX, learn beamer, learn the combination). If you have the impression that the cost/gain ratio is not as good as you hoped then you should reconsider why you dismissed PowerPoint in the first place ("would take me 5 minutes" is a strong argument). Why did you, by the way?

Answer (score 27):

In this answer, I will explain how to make animations in both PDF and GIF format:

Make sure you have installed the following applications and set the PATH system variable to their locations.

1. TeXLive or MikTeX.
2. GhostScript. You can install either the 32 or 64 bit version. The corresponding application names for 32 bit and 64 bit are `gswin32c.exe` and `gswin64c.exe` repectively.
3. ImageMagick. It is required to create GIF animations. You can install either the 32 or 64  bit version.

The first two sections will guide you to create some supporting files that will simplify your workflow. The last section will show how to make use of the supporting files to create animations.

### Creating A Multi Purpose Batch File for GIF Animation

Create a batch file named `GifAnimate.bat` as follows. It is recommended to save it in a separate directory such that any other projects can make use of it. Don't forget to set the PATH to its location.

```
rem this is GifAnimate.bat

rem %1 : filename (without extension) of a PDF file having pages to be animated.

rem %2 : delay between frames (in 1/100 miliseconds).

rem %3 : density of the GIF output. The higher it is the bigger output.

echo off

rem remove the previous GIF animation if any.
del %1.gif

convert -delay %2 -loop 0 -density %3 %1.pdf %1.gif
```

### Creating A Multi Purpose Batch File and Template for PDF Animation

Create a batch file named `PdfAnimate.bat` as follows. It is recommended to save it in a separate directory such that any other projects can make use of it. Don't forget to set the PATH to its location.

```
rem this is PdfAnimate.bat

rem %1 : filename (without extension) of a PDF file having pages to be animated.

rem %2 : frame rate (in frames per second).

rem %3 : scale of the GIF output. The higher it is the bigger output.

echo off

rename %1.pdf %1-animate.pdf

pdflatex -interaction=batchmode --jobname=%1 "\newcommand\InputFileName{%1-animate}\newcommand\FrameRate{%2}\newcommand\OutputScale{%3}\input{PdfAnimateTemplate}"

del %1-animate.pdf
```

Create a template file named `PdfAnimateTemplate.tex` as follows. It is recommended to save it in your local TDS such that any other projects can make use of it.

```
% this is PdfAnimateTemplate.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,scale=\OutputScale]{\FrameRate}{\InputFileName}{}{}       
\end{document}
```

### Creating GIF and PDF Animations

Create a LaTeX input file named `test.tex` as follows:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\psset{plotpoints=3000,algebraic}


\begin{document}
\multido{\r=-3.5+0.5}{15}
{
    \begin{pspicture}(-4,-2)(4,2)
        \psaxes[arrows=->,linewidth=0.2pt](0,0)(-3.5,-1.5)(3.5,1.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
        \psplot[linecolor=red]{-3.5}{\r}{sin(3*x)}
    \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

First compile it with either LaTeX or XeLaTeX.

With LaTeX is as follows (do one after another):

```
latex test.tex
dvips test.dvi
ps2pdf test.ps
```

With XeLaTeX is as follows:

```
xelatex test.tex
```

You will have a PDF output named `test.pdf`. It consists of 15 pages.

To get the corresponding GIF animation, execute `GifAnimate.bat test 20 250`, we will get the following output:

[image]

To get the corresponding PDF animation, execute `PdfAnimate.bat test 25 3`, we will get a PDF animation (cannot be shown here).

### Miscellaneous

Responding to [Yiannis Lazarides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/963/yiannis-lazarides)' comment below. I am lazy to animate Batman as the curve has many discontinuities. Instead, I present another example. Hopefully the following graph is more exciting!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\psset{viewpoint=50 20 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth}


\begin{document}
\multido{\rx=-0.5+0.05,\ry=-0.45+0.05,\i=1+1}{20}
{
    \begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(0.5,0.5)
    \rput(0,0){%
    \begin{pspicture*}(-0.5,-0.5)(0.5,0.5)
        \defFunction[algebraic]{helicespherique}(t)
        {0.5*cos(10*t)*cos(t)}
        {0.5*sin(10*t)*cos(t)}
        {0.5*sin(t)}
        \ifnum\i=1
        \psSolid
        [
            object=sphere,
            linewidth=0.1pt,
            linecolor=red,
            resolution=720,
            action=draw*,
            ngrid=9 9,
            r=0.5
        ]\fi
        \psSolid
        [
            object=courbe,
            linewidth=0.05pt,
            linecolor=blue,
            resolution=720,
            range=pi \rx\space mul \ry\space pi mul,
            function=helicespherique,
            r=0.01
        ]
    \end{pspicture*}}
    \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

### Responding to the given comment

If you want to animate `test.pdf` (consists of 15 pages) in your PDF document, use the following template and compile with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
% your other contents go here
\animategraphics[autoplay,loop,scale=<OutputScale>]{<FrameRate>}{test}{}{}
% your other contents go here      
\end{document}
```

where

- `<OutputScale>` is a real number representing the scaling factor.
- `<FrameRate>` is an integer representing frames per second.

Of course, `<` and `>` are not the part of the syntax.

Comment: Great example! Can you use a more exciting curve? Maybe the batman?

Comment: **Full disclaimer:** I haven't actually tried your solution but I'm being nit picky anyway. In your first `.bat` file, there is a space before each file ending (`del %1. gif`) but in the second there isn't (`del %1-animate.pdf`). Just double checking that this is intentional.

Comment: How has the example to be modified, if I want do include more animations to the final pdf?

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger: Sorry for replying late because I did not notice your comment. See my last edit at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to use the [animate](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/animate) package. Have a look for an example on page 14 of its [manual](http://ctan.yazduni.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf). You will need to use Acrobat Reader to view it properly.