# Animate pgfplot graph using animate package

Tags: pgfplots, plot, animate

After googling how to animate a plot I found different ways that I didn't get, I've done some animations before using this [method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401886/how-to-create-simple-animations-with-animate). My question is it possible to use the same method to animate the following plot ?

[image]

( I need this animation in few days so I'm not able to learn other methods )

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {0,1,...,20} {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-3,-5) rectangle (9,10);
\begin{axis}[%title={test},
             legend style={font=\fontsize{3}{3}\selectfont},
             legend pos=south east,
             axis lines=center,
             domain=0.2:8,
             xtick={0,1,...,7},
             ytick={0,1,...,4},
             samples=501,
             xlabel={}]
\addplot [gray, dashed] {1};

\addplot [color=red] {1-exp(-\x)*cos(3*deg(\x))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean for "animate a plot"?

Comment: Like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56461/animated-plotting-with-latex @vipa

Comment: Do you want a GIF in which the plot is draw point by point? Or an animation of the plot on a PDF file?

Comment: I want a GIF in which the plot is drawn point by point @vipa

Comment: For usage in a WEB page, SVG would also be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the problem at hand, the upper bound of the plotting domain needs to be animated.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
%\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone} % latex <file>.tex ; dvisvgm --font-format=woff2 --zoom=-1  --exact <file>.dvi 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[controls]{20}
\multiframe{81}{rXmax=0+0.1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    domain=0.001:\rXmax,
    xtick={0,1,...,8},
    xmax=8.4,
    ymax=1.6,
    samples=501
  ]
  \addplot [gray, dashed] {1};
  
  \addplot [color=red] {1-exp(-x)*cos(3*deg(x))};
  
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have found that the conversion to GIF is much better if you add a background to the tikzpicture in the standalone class.

Comment: @vipa You can do that with `convert`. Add option `-alpha remove`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution use [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/) and must be compiled (only the first time for get the table of the points of the curve) using `pdflatex.exe -shell-escape %.tex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{math,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\foreach \xDom in {0.2,0.3,...,7.2} {
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=white},show background rectangle]
\tikzmath{
\samplePoints= int(\xDom*100);
\idFile= int(\xDom*10);
}
\begin{axis}[%title={test},
             legend style={font=\fontsize{3}{3}\selectfont},
             legend pos=south east,
             axis lines=center,
             domain=0.2:\xDom,
             xmin=0.2,xmax=7.5,
             ymin={1-exp(-0.2)*cos(3*deg(0.2))},
             ymax=1.5,
             xtick={0,1,...,7},
             ytick={0,1,...,4},
             samples=\samplePoints,
             xlabel={}]
\draw[gray, dashed] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:7.2,1);

\addplot [color=red] gnuplot[id=gr\idFile] {1-exp(-x)*cos(3*x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

As can be see I have add a background to the tikzpicture, because I have found that conversion to GIF is much better in this way (less aliased).
After the compilation of the LaTeX code you must convert the multi page PDF to GIF using `ImageMagick`. I use the following istruction in the command line:

```
magick convert -verbose -density 300 -strip -resize 50% -layers OptimizePlus -delay 30 *.pdf myGIF.gif
```

If you don't use Windows omit the initial `magick`

The result is:

[image]

**Edit:**
As AlexG say it's not neccessary the background, you can use the flag `-alpha remove` in `convert`.
Therefore an improved code (with some other changes) is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}

\foreach \xDom [count=\idFile] in {0.2,0.21,...,7.2} {
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{
\samplePoints= ifthenelse(\xDom==0.2, 1, int(\xDom*100));
}
\begin{axis}[%title={test},
             legend style={font=\fontsize{3}{3}\selectfont},
             legend pos=south east,
             axis lines=center,
             domain=0.2:\xDom,
             xmin=0.2,xmax=7.5,
             ymin={1-exp(-0.2)*cos(3*deg(0.2))},
             ymax=1.5,
             xtick={0,1,...,7},
             ytick={0,1,...,4},
             samples=\samplePoints,
             xlabel={}]
\draw[gray, dashed] (axis cs:0,1) -- (axis cs:7.2,1);

\addplot [color=red] gnuplot[id=gr\idFile] {1-exp(-x)*cos(3*x)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

As before this must be compiled with `pdflatex.exe -shell-escape %.tex` for get the multipage PDF and then with:

```
magick convert -verbose -density 300 -strip -resize 40% -alpha remove -layers OptimizePlus -delay 1 *.pdf myGif.gif
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! Just a question, is it possible to have a smoother animation ?  @vipa

Comment: @Hibou See my edit answer.